# How to Pin Columns to the Filters Pane. (Pnp.PowerShell)

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, filter, pnp-powershell

[image]

https://sharepointmaven.com/how-to-add-custom-metadata-columns-to-the-filters-pane-in-sharepoint-online/
Refer to step 5 of this webpage.

Can it be implemented using PowerShell?